# List mp3 files from multiple directories

Tags: php, html

I have a problem again... My directory structure is:

```
mp3/
   /CD1/
       /test1.mp3
       /test2.mp3 ...
   /CD2/
       /test3.mp3 ...
```

I'm trying to get an output such as spotify like, all info taken from the dir structure:

CD1 ---- Songs: test1.mp3  / test2.mp3 / ...

Then scan next folder and output:

CD2 ---- Songs: test3.mp3 / ...

And for succesive folders.

I am able to output ALL files inside the mp3 dir, but thats not what I want.

The admin has to be able to add a new folder "CD3" and the .php page has to show the new folder and its songs.

CD3 ---- Songs: test4.mp3 / ...

I don't know if this is possible... I'm trying to setup the code so that the webpage admin does not need to touch any of the code, but only the file structure.

THANKS!

The idea of what I want is here: http://qalbiol.x10.mx/qalbiol/sounds.php

The above works because I manually set mp3/CD1 as search dir, then set mp3/CD2 as search dir...

Comment: "Manually" setting the directory sounds like an ok solution - get the top level directory listing, and then loop through the CD1, CD2, etc directories

Comment: Hey thanks, I figured out how to do it! It is as simple as you said, but I'm new into php... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this for images, not sure if this may help:

```
$path = WWW.'/images/user-images/public';
if(is_dir($path)){
    $dir1 = opendir($path);

    while($scan = readdir($dir1)){ 
        if(is_dir($path.'/'.$scan) && $scan != '..' && $scan != '.'){
            $dir2 = opendir($path.'/'.$scan);
            $counter = 0;
            while($images = readdir($dir2)){
                if(!is_dir($images) && $images != '..' && $images != '.'){
                    $allImages[$counter] = $images;
                    $counter++;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it with my code, now works perfectly. BUT, I'll definitely try your code as I'm doing the same for my images, and it's giving me problems! Thanks again!